# is there anything like _get_hovered in jsTree?

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, jstree

using [jsTreev pre 1 stable](http://jstree.com) and hotkeys plugin.

I have a function that is fired when 'return' is pressed. I want get text of the node that was hovered before pressing enter. This code `$.jstree._focused().get_selected().text()` works **ONLY** if I click the node with my mouse and then press enter.

**How can I get the text without using mouse?**

I was thinking that _get_hovered would be nice to have.

when I use only keyboard the class for the node I am going to press enter changes and gets new class `jstree-hovered`. I thought I can use it somehow but I don't know how.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You actually almost provided your own solution within your question: as jsTree (ever so nicely) adds the `jstree-hovered` class to the node that is currently being hovered over, all you need to do is find which node has this class from withing your "return" key event handling code.

```
jQuery("#tree").jstree({
  plugins: [ "themes","html_data","ui","crrm", "hotkeys" ],
  hotkeys: {
    "return" : function () {
      $hovered = $('#tree .jstree-hovered');
      if ($hovered.length) {
        alert('Hovered node text: ' + $hovered.text());
      } else {
        alert('No element was hovered over when return was pressed');
      }
    }
  }
});
```

Working example at http://jsfiddle.net/y7XVp/16/

Comment: I thought that there will be `native jsTree` way how to tackle this.  Why do you search for '#tree .jstree-hovered' and not only 'jstree.hovered'?

Comment: It's just a personal preference of mine, to narrow down selectors to the smallest possible subsets, but of course .jstree-hovered will work nicely. I just don't like to search through the whole DOM, when it's not necessary.